# Unable to get correct DbContext reference in ASP.NET Core action filters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I wanted to call the entity framework's `SaveChangesAsync()` for every request in an `IAsyncActionFilter`.

Here is my IAsyncActionFilter:

**DbContextSaveChangesFilter.cs**

```
public class DbContextSaveChangesFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public DbContextSaveChangesFilter(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) 
    {
        var result = await next();
        if (result.Exception == null || result.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

So, the `SaveChangesAsync()` will be called after any changes are made by my service methods:

**Service.cs**

```
private readonly DbContext _dbContext
public MyService(DbContext dbContext) {
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}

public void SomeServiceMethod() {
    var myEntity = _dbContext.MyEntities.First();
    myEntity.Name = model.Name;
}
```

**Problem**

The problem is that I am getting a two different references to `_dbContext` in the service and in the filter. That is, the `_dbContext` that is injected into my service is different instance from the one injected in the filter.

Calling `_dbContext.GetHashCode()` in the filter and in the service results in two different numbers.

**Versions**

```
.NET Core: 2.2.402
ASP.NET:   2.2.0
EF Core:   2.2.6
Sql Server:2019 EXPRESS
```

EDIT:
This is how I am configuring my DbContext in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(opts =>
{
    opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

and here is how I am registering my filter inside `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddMvc(o =>
{    
    o.Filters.Add(typeof(DbContextSaveChangesFilter));
});
```

Comment: How do you register this filter?

Comment: @EugenePodskal I have updated my question to include that.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can't do this with `IAsyncActionFilter`, because [`OnActionExecutionAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncactionfilter.onactionexecutionasync?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_IAsyncActionFilter_OnActionExecutionAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ActionExecutingContext_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ActionExecutionDelegate_) is

> Called asynchronously *before* the action, after model binding is complete.

So you're too early, which probably means that the filter has received its own context instance from the DI container. Which was also to be expected since the filter is asynchronous. But even with a shared instance `SaveChanges` wouldn't do anything at that point.

So *if* you want to do this you need to implement [`IActionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iactionfilter?view=aspnetcore-3.0), and use its `OnActionExecuted` method. I think the DI container will supply you with the same context as the one in the controller, when it's registered as scoped to the request. If not, you might want to play around with `ActionExecutingContext`'s `Controller` property, but that always requires code constructs in which the controller's context must be publicly (or at least internally) accessible.

As you see, I'm not spelling this out in code, because I think you shouldn't do this. Call `SaveChanges` *visibly* where it's needed and nowhere else. You *certainly* don't want to risk saving changes that aren't supposed to be saved (it's easily overlooked). Nor do you want to call `SaveChanges` when a method only reads data.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are actually injecting `MyDbContext` into `MyService` (not `DbContext` as shown - `DbContext` would not have a `MyEntities` property).

The `AddDbContext` method only adds an instance of `MyDbContext` to your pipeline, not `DbContext`.

Try to either:

1. Change `DbContextSaveChangesFilter` to take an instance of `MyDbContext` instead of `DbContext`:

   ```cs
   private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

   public DbContextSaveChangesFilter(MyDbContext dbContext)
   {
       _dbContext = dbContext;
   }
   ```

   or:
2. Tell your pipeline to also resolve `DbContext` to `MyDbContext`:

   ```cs
   services.AddScoped<DbContext, MyDbContext>();
   ```